# Get option from ui.draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am inside the drop event:

I have this ui.draggable which is the element I dragged and dropped to enter the drop event.

I have setup the `ui.draggable` with

```
$(element).draggable("option", "cursorAt", {
        left: $(element).width(),
        top: $(element).height()
    });
```

How can I get now from ui.draggable the option object to reset the left/top values from cursorAt property to zero?

I tried this:

```
var option = $(ui.draggable[0]).draggable('option');
```

and I seem to get option.cursorAt.left = xx;

but is that the right way? Do I have to wrap a draggable again with draggable function? That seems counter-intuitive and wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(element).draggable("option", "cursorAt", {
    left: 0,
    top: 0
});
```

See [cursorAt](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cursorAt)